# Fatal error: Call to a member function first() on a non-object

Tags: php, oop

Yes I know there is a lot of questions about this topic I searched and tried all answers but none of them helped me.
That's why I created another question with my own code.

```
class Student{
    private $_db,
            $_first;

public function __construct() {
    $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
}

public function getLast($fields = array()) {
    $columns = 'admission_no, id';
    $orderBy = 'id';
    $order = 'DESC';

    if(!empty($fields['columns'])){
        $columns = $fields['columns'];
    }

    if(!empty($fields['order_by'])){
        $orderBy = $fields['oder_by'];
    }

    if(!empty($fields['order'])){
        $order = $fields['order'];
    }

    $data = $this->_db->query("SELECT {$columns} FROM students ORDER BY {$orderBy} {$order} LIMIT 1");

    if($data->count()){
        $this->_first = $data->first();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public function first() {
    return $this->_first;
}

}
```

Above is the code of the Student Class.
And in below code I am calling Student class, while calling student class I get this error.

```
$student = new Student;

$admission = $student->getLast()->first();
$admission_no = $admission->admission_no;

echo $admission_no;
```

Can you guys can give me any hints or clue.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: Maybe you are missing a semicolon at the end of your private variables declaration? private $_db; private $_first;

Comment: I'd also instantiate: $student = new Student(); with ()

Comment: @davidvelilla ohh Sorry! I missed it in question. In my code I have a semicolon. Also edited question and added semicolon.

Comment: @davidvelilla I tried Student(); class with parenthesis but it didnt worked and showing the same error

Comment: getLast() will always return either "true", "false", or fail before. In no case will it return an object that then you can use to call "first()"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$admission = $student->getLast()->first();
```

This piece of code is totally bad. You call method first() on result of method getLast() not on $student object. getLast() return true or false that is not object for sure. Try:

```
$student->getLast();
$admission = $student->first();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call methods chained, you must return `$this` on each method.
ie:

```
 class FormHelper {

    protected $input;
    protected $type;
    protected $name;

    public function input() {
        $this->input = '<input ';
        return $this;
    }

    public function type($type) {
        $this->type = $type;
        return $this;
    }

    public function name($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function render() {
        $out = "{$this->input} type=\"{$this->type}\" name=\"{$this->name}\" />";
        echo $out;
    }

  }

  $form = new FormHelper();

  $form->input()->type('text')->name('email')->render();
```

Comment: Thank you for this extra knowledge. You also clear alot of my other confusions.